# problem with Downloading files/video with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, download

I tried using the following function to download. but the files downloaded have more size than the original file.

```py
import os
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import threading

def download_chunk(url, save_folder, filename, start_byte, end_byte, progress_bar):
    headers = {'Range': f'bytes={start_byte}-{end_byte}'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True, allow_redirects=True)

    with open(os.path.join(save_folder, filename), 'ab') as file:
        for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
            file.write(data)
            progress_bar.update(len(data))

def download_with_progress(url, save_folder, filename, num_threads=4):
    response = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
    file_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))

    if response.status_code == 200:
        block_size = file_size // num_threads
        progress_bar = tqdm(total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True)

        with open(os.path.join(save_folder, filename), 'wb') as file:
            file.truncate(file_size)

        threads = []

        for i in range(num_threads):
            start_byte = i * block_size
            end_byte = start_byte + block_size - 1 if i < num_threads - 1 else file_size - 1
            print(f"Thread {i}: Downloading bytes {start_byte}-{end_byte}")
            thread = threading.Thread(target=download_chunk, args=(url, save_folder, filename, start_byte, end_byte, progress_bar))
            threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

        progress_bar.close()
        print(f"Downloaded {filename}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download file. Status code: {response.status_code}")


# Example usage:
download_with_progress("https://example.com/download.mp4", "GoogleColab", "hellyrev.mp4", num_threads=20)
# Google colab is dir
```

i want to download the file quickly cause the file download is too slow. But, downloaded file is bigger than the original file. Please, help me with this.

I tried to download file from url with multhreading to increase overall dl speed. But, downloaded file is larger than the original.

Comment: You're saving data from multiple threads to one file in random order. It will be a mess!

Comment: Get it working with one thread first. Then explain to us why you think using multiple threads will be quicker. It won't. The network isn't multi-threaded, and neither is your hard disk.

Comment: instead of making my own module for downloading. I am currently using pypdl. Aw, thank you for suggestions though. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution I found and implemented

```py
from pypdl import Downloader

url = "https://mysite.site/file.pdf"
dest = "/content/GoogleColab/lfab.mp4"

dl = Downloader()
dl.start(url, dest, num_connections=10, display=True, multithread=True)
```

It'll download the file with progress. Pysmartdl is also good, but it's(pypdl) more convenient for me.